# Output JSON array without the class name in every array element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

The default way to output JSON in rails is some thing like:
Code:
`render :json => friends.to_json(:only => [:username, :avatar_file_name, :id ])`

Output

```
{"friends" : 
  [{"user": 
    {"avatar_file_name": "image1.jpg", "username": "user1", "id": 1}},
   {"user": 
    {"avatar_file_name": "image2.jpg", "username": "user2", "id": 2}},
   {"user":
    {"avatar_file_name": "image3.jpg", "username": "user3", "id": 3}}
  ]}
```

But i want something like:

```
{"friends" : 
    {"user": [
      {"avatar_file_name": "image1.jpg", "username": "user1", "id": 1},
      {"avatar_file_name": "image2.jpg", "username": "user2", "id": 2},
      {"avatar_file_name": "image3.jpg", "username": "user3", "id": 3}
    ]}
}
```

The class is specified by the array name.
Last.fm also uses this syntax see [Last.fm 'API-user.getfriends'](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=fgeertsema&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json)

Comment: Tip: Use http://json.bloople.net/ for a nice visual representation of the JSON array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to this problem is commenting the line
`ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true`
in `initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb`

Or setting `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` to false.

Comment: is there no solution to satisfy just one function? As this would break other JSON calls that already exist in the app

Comment: sure, just add root: nil to your render call in controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to reformat it:

```
var json = 
{
  "friends" : 
  { "user": [] }
}

var i = 0;
for ( x in friends )
{
     json.friends.user[i].avatar_file_name = x.user.avatar_file_name; // add more fields.
     i++;
}
```

Something among those lines.

Comment: The output is going to be used in an iphone app. So the output will not be parsed via javascript but directly converted to objective-C objects. I want the right json file directly from rails. Thank you for your aswer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is normally used to represent objects in a text format.

So if you like the secon output you must change your objects.

The first output says:
there is a *friends* object which is a array of *user*, each user has some properties among which you chose to expose *username, avatar_file_name, id*

The second output says:
there is a *friends* object which contains a *user* object which is an array of unnamed objects, each unnamed objects has some properties...

This second output is not writable in JSON syntax.

It might be:

```
{"friends" : 
    {"user": [
      ["avatar_file_name", "username", "id"],
      ["image1.jpg", "user1", 1],
      ["image2.jpg", "user2", 2],
      ["image3.jpg", "user3", 3]
    ]}
}
```

This says:
there is a *friends* object which contains a *user* object which is an array of array (a table with field names on first row) ...

Comment: Last.fm also uses the same syntax as my second output. See edited question.